# Где взять задачи(идеи) для закрепления материала по пройденым темам?

Tags: java

Изучил Java syntax и сейчас заканчиваю Java core На курсе JavaRush. Ощущается, что тяжело уже все идет, мотивация падает из-за того, что не понимаешь что-то или даже больше из-за того, что каша в голове.

Суть моего вопроса в общем в том, чтобы хотелось еще больше практики, мини проекты какие-то, но не тупо отсортировать коллекцию определенным образом, а чтобы была задумка какая-то интересная(например мини игра, парсер с сайта) но графику еще не изучал, поэтому только консоль. Может кто подсказать подобные интересные задачи?

Comment: `Где взять задачи(идеи) для закрепления материала по пройденым темам?` - на работе

Comment: + список идей которые можно поделать https://github.com/karan/Projects

Comment: На работе в голову приходят идеи, но знаний не достаточно моих для таких идей. Нужна практика мне, в консоли, из-за этого как-то сложно придумать

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, хорошая ссылка, видел ее. Взял от туда несколько задач для практики. Но я там или еще не изучал некоторые темы или они (задачи) скучные

Comment: криптовалютный бот-трейдер

Comment: @Sebastian1 `На работе в голову приходят идеи, но знаний не достаточно моих для таких идей.` - поэтому идут джуном работать за еду, а не сразу Senior  ;-)

Comment: "они (задачи) скучные " не всегда же работа веселая. Опешите какие задачи вам ну скучные и может тут найдется тот кто будет их для вас придумывать ориентируясь на список ваших знаний.

Comment: java rush ведь шляпный ресурс

Answer (score 1):

Свои идеи для тренировки я беру из головы либо придумываю как можно облегчить работу своих родственников, друзей. У меня есть товарищ, который занимается подготовкой документов на тендеры. Так вот эта работа очень однообразная, предлагал ему написать сервис, где он будет вставлять в поля нужные ему данные и в конечном итоге сервис сформирует ему документ целиком. Второй пример - знакомая работает администратором салона красоты, но учет ведется на бумаге, есть желание это "оптимизировать". Третий пример - хожу по сайтам и думаю, что бы хотел сам "повторить". Конечно это не тот уровень знаний, которые у меня есть, т.к. я сам только недавно начал изучать C# и программирование в целом, но тем не менее по чуть-чуть то тут, то там, а опыт складывается в копилку.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего - предложить любому знакомому бесплатно разработать программу для его вида деятельности. Тогда он будет мотивирован, поставить задачу и контролировать ее реализацию. На "боевых" проектах учиться лучше всего